# Strong consistency within transactions in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Google Cloud Datastore is a non-relational database, and is built on the concept of [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#what-is-eventual-consistency). It also supplies a means to get strong consistency through [ancestor queries and entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#ancestor-query-and-entity-group). However, I am not getting strong consistency when using ancestor queries within a [transaction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions).

Consider this:

```
class Child(ndb.Model):

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        child = cls()
        child.put()
        print Child.query().fetch()

Child.create()
```

Since this did not use an entity group, it operates with eventual consistency. As expected, we get:

```
[]
```

Let's try it using entity groups and an ancestor query:

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):

    pass


class Child(ndb.Model):

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, parent):
        child = cls(parent=parent)
        child.put()
        print Child.query(ancestor=parent).fetch()


parent = Parent().put()
Child.create(parent)
```

Here we get strong consistency, so the output is:

```
[Child(key=Key('Parent', <id>, 'Child', <id>))]
```

However, when we throw a transaction into the mix:

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):

    pass


class Child(ndb.Model):

    @classmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def create(cls, parent):
        child = cls(parent=parent)
        child.put()
        print Child.query(ancestor=parent).fetch()


parent = Parent().put()
Child.create(parent)
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

Given that translations are meant to primarily work with ancestor queries (the cross-group flag even exists just to get around that requirement), why is strong consistency being lost inside a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#isolation_and_consistency) do address your last example:

> Unlike with most databases, queries and gets inside a Cloud Datastore
>   transaction do not see the results of previous writes inside that
>   transaction. Specifically, if an entity is modified or deleted within
>   a transaction, a query or get returns the original version of the
>   entity as of the beginning of the transaction, or nothing if the
>   entity did not exist then.

I can't explain this better than the Google docs do, but this is intended behavior for transactions based on how Google implements transaction isolation.

Comment: As per usual, I read Google's docs multiple times, yet seemed to miss the key information I was looking for. I do think it'd be helpful for the docs on ancestor queries to mention transaction isolation to prevent the confusion/frustration I experienced. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!